# HTTP headers are incorrectly treated case sensitive by jClouds causing OpenStack x-storage-url to fail

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, openstack, openstack-swift, jclouds

We are using the jclouds library for connection to OpenStack Swift (grizzly) cloud storage, and are running into the following issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-155

We are using Apache web front for the swift proxy as defined here:
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/apache_deployment_guide.html

Essentially the issue is that the Apache web front (using mod-wsgi) returns a lower case header (x-storage-url), whereas jClouds is expecting it to be X-Storage-URL (case-sensitive).

So the jClouds is being case-sensitive. When it shouldn't be. Is there anything we can do to work around this, while someone from the jClouds community fixes this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed and release in [jclouds 1.6.2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.jclouds.api%7Cswift%7C1.6.2-incubating%7Cbundle).